# Display indicator only on specific timeframes

Tags: visibility, pine-script

This is my first post and I am a beginner with pinescript.

For Indicators like EMA, under settings there is a tab for "Visibility" where it can be selected which timeframes that the indicator is displayed.  By default it is set to have visibility on all timeframes, and everytime the indicator is modified, the Visibiltiy resets to All timeframes.

Is there a pinescript that will set default Visiblity to only Minutes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually by testing for timeframe values. You could also optionally add inputs to be able to toggle it on/off or have other options.

```
display_only_minutes = timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= 60

ma = sma(close, 50)

plot(display_only_minutes ? ma : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
//@version=5

indicator('hide indicator by specific timeframe', overlay=true)
basePeriods = input.int(15, minval=1, title='Base Line Length')
donchian(len) =>
    math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)

hourly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', baseLine , lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
daily = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', baseLine , lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
weekly = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', baseLine , lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(timeframe.multiplier==240 ? hourly : na, title='Base Line', trackprice=true, color=color.new(#991515, 0), linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isdaily ? daily : na, title='Base Line', trackprice=true, color=color.new(#149a1b, 0), linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isweekly ? weekly : na, title='Base Line', trackprice=true, color=color.new(#341599, 0), linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).